# will I need to pick up & recheck bags with layover in Calgary?

Tags: transit, luggage, canada

I'm flying from US on Westjet (affiliated with Delta) from Minneapolis to Edmonton via a 1hr 22min stopover in Calgary. Will I need to pick up and recheck my bags in Calgary?

Comment: Are both flights on the same ticket? Both actual westjet flights?

Comment: You need to ask the airline if no one specifically knows. You'll clear immigration in Calgary and would normally expect to pick up your luggage going through customs, but [YYC has a fancy new international terminal](http://www.yyc.com/CALGARYAIRPORTAUTHORITY/NewInternationalTerminal/Blog/TabId/785/ArtMID/1885/ArticleID/26/New-International-Terminal-Will-Soon-Open-to-the-World.aspx) and the baggage handling system may be capable of just forwarding the luggage if they don't want to look at it.